# Why does knife project cut only one hole into a disc?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I used the spin operator to duplicate a circle, after that I tried to knife project all circles (single object), all the duplicated circles don't have an effect but the original circle is cut out. Why is that?

[image]

[.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/27887)

It's a [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T39421)

Comment: The knife project tool does odd things like that, I know. I haven't figured it out either yet.

Comment: I know that cutting holes into mesh in general is a problem. What happens if you place the circles slightly over the so that it is not actually a hole?

Comment: @Vader it seems that knife project needs intersecting edges to cut properly.

Comment: Stacker, I'm having a discussion about this issue now on [BlenderArtist.org](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331554-Why-does-knife-project-not-cut-properly-if-target-mesh-is-not-subdivided&p=2607876#post2607876)

Comment: @ThomBlairIII oh, thank you i added the link to the bug report.

Comment: It'd be nice to see "it's a bug" as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Matt for the time being the workaround appears to be more useful for users facing this issue.

Comment: True, it might be better for "it's a bug" to be **part** of the accepted answer, but the real answer to "Why?" is "it's a bug." This is helpful in clarifying the difference between something **I'm** doing wrong and something **Blender** is doing wrong.

Comment: The linked bug report says that the example was a user error after all (double vertices). @stacker Care to add an answer with the solution in the report? (if it worked and is the case here, that is..)

Comment: @stacker your paste all link is dead

Comment: @David Yes, in this case the .blend is easy to reproduce. We hadn't a solution at the time: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-a-service-for-uploading-blendfiles/300#300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by subdividing the target object a lot:

[image]

When the target was not subdivided, not all of the knife circles would cut, but once I subdivided, they all cut. I have no idea why though.

However, trying to get it to work on a cylinder is more difficult. The way I got around it was:

1. Add a circle mesh and set the Fill type to Triangle Fan:

   [image]
2. Then when you do the knife projection, all the circles will cut:

   [image]
3. Then you can extrude the cut circle into your cylinder